# What versions of dotnetstandard does Xamarin support?

Tags: .net, xamarin

I'm not sure which versions of .Net Standard are supported by Xamarin. Many examples I saw somehow target `dotnetstandard 1.4`
This image suggests that all (namely 1.0 to 1.6) are supported?

## [image: .Net Platforms Support]

Comment: If you are looking for current **multiple** IDE support (Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio for Mac or Windows), it would be 1.5 as of this comment

Comment: As a small note, you want to support the lowest version of `netstandard` as you can with your apps. There is support all the way to 1.6 and soon to be 2.0. However the apis get more narrow the higher you go with `netstandard`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin supports .NET standard 1.0 - 2.0.

I think the examples are only targeting 1.4, because 1.5 and 1.6 are "mistakes". You should not use these two versions. Quote from Immo Landwerth (the program manager of .NET) https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/On-NET/Immo-Landwerth-Net-Standard

Answer (score 0):

That chart means Xamarin is likely to support all standard versions up to 1.6.

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/4.6.0/

As Mono 4.6 claims to be 1.6 compliant, the corresponding Xamarin bits should also support this (after Sept 13, 2016).

Microsoft should update their documentation to reflect such recent changes, because it already leads to so much confusion.

Comment: by "likely" you mean they intend, but do not (yet) support it (at least not officially)? Or you mean they state they support it?

Comment: @yyannekk neither confirmation nor denial but you can try.

Comment: yeah that's true. the problem sometimes is, trying new stuff - as xamarin is to me - you run in to several problems, and you don't know where they come from. so im seeking a definite answer. but y i trial and error ofc

Comment: @yyannekk it would be a good question for Xamarin/Microsoft support/presale team but not for Stack Overflow. You should challenge who develop that.

Comment: @yyannekk I have updated the answer. You should definitely get 1.6 support on Xamarin right now.

Answer (score 0):

The chart is saying that all versions of Xamarin support netstandard-1.6.

The arrows are somewhat confusing but they are stating that a library that targets, say, netstandard-1.0 will run on Xamarin because it supports netstandard-1.6. The opposite is very much not the case.